# pytest parametrize tests run all scenario in parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen, pytest, pytest-django

I can run pytest paramatrize tests one after other as below

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("asetup", ['a1','a2'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("bsetup", ['b1','b2'])
```

Here are 4 scenarios. Can I run then all in parallel?

```
  <Function 'test_1[b1-a1]'>
  <Function 'test_1[b1-a2]'>
  <Function 'test_1[b2-a1]'>
  <Function 'test_1[b2-a2]'>
```

I tried using xdist but it still runs one after other.

```
py.test -d --tx 3*popen//python=python2.7 tests_suite.py -vv -k 'test_1' -s
```

I changed `scope` from `module` to `function`, but I don't see them running in parallel.

`@pytest.fixture(scope="function")`

Comment: What if you just try with the `-n` parameter? (`-n 3`)

Comment: I tried that but still running sequentially

Comment: Any luck with this?